# Password Strength level in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to implement a password Checker,
for example the password should contain one upper case, one small case, one special character at least.

But I want to make it separate, for example if the user doesn't enter an upper case I show him that the missing one is upper.

Here my implementation but it's not working:

```
const handlePasswordChange = (text) => {
let count = 0;
// One uppercase character
if (text.match(/^[A-Z]*$/)) {
  count++;
  setPasswordChecks((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    upperCase: { ...prev.upperCase, isValid: true },
  }));
} else {
  setPasswordChecks((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    upperCase: { ...prev.upperCase, isValid: false },
  }));
}
if (text.toUpperCase() !== text) {
  count++;
  setPasswordChecks((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    lowerCase: { ...prev.lowerCase, isValid: true },
  }));
} else {
  setPasswordChecks((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    lowerCase: { ...prev.lowerCase, isValid: false },
  }));
}

var format = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;

if (format.test(text)) {
  setPasswordChecks((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    specialCharacter: { ...prev.specialCharacter, isValid: true },
  }));
} else {
  setPasswordChecks((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    specialCharacter: { ...prev.specialCharacter, isValid: false },
  }));
}

// Check Level
console.log('count:: ', count);
if (count === 0 || count === 1) {
  setPasswordStrength('low');
} else if (count === 4) {
  setPasswordStrength('high');
} else {
  setPasswordStrength('medium');
}
```

};

Is there a better way to implement this ?

Comment: It's not working is no a valid problem description

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get errors? Or is it failing logically?

Comment: Logically, if I entered first letter as Big letter the if for upper case get triggered, but not when I enter many small letters than one Big letter for example